# Save data to Sqlite Database with using fragment_Tabbed Activity

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm new at Android. Trying to save data to Sqlite database. I'm using Tabbed Activity so there are fragments in my project. I couldn't understand how to communicate my database with fragment. I want to take user name with etAdi(edit text id) and save with bKaydet(Button Save). 
I tried to put

*final Veritabani veritabani=new Veritabani(getActivity());*

this code(Veritabani means Database) but when i use veritabani.open() and veritabani.close() taking error in app. Tried to write this Database codes in to SubPage01.java(Fragment) . Please help..

My Database class: Veritabani.java

**Veritabani.java**

```
package com.guly.projecttabmenu;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import layout.SubPage01;

public class Veritabani{

    public static final String ROW_ID = "id";
    public static final String ROW_NAME = "adi";
    public static final String ROW_SURNAME = "soyadi";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "veritabani";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CUSTOMERINFORMATION_TABLE = "customerinformation"; //customerinformation = kisiler

    private Context ourContext;
    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;



    public  Veritabani(Context context)
    {
       ourContext=context;

    }



    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + CUSTOMERINFORMATION_TABLE + "(" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ROW_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ROW_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + CUSTOMERINFORMATION_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }



    public Veritabani open(){

        ourHelper=new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public Veritabani close(){

        ourHelper.close();
        return this;
    }


}

`
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.guly.projecttabmenu;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.guly.projecttabmenu/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.guly.projecttabmenu/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    //Veri tabanı oluşturuyoruz
    Veritabani veritabani = new Veritabani(MainActivity.this);

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                SubPage01 tab1 = new SubPage01();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                subPage02 tab2 = new subPage02();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                subPage03 tab3 = new subPage03();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;}

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Müşteri Kaydet";
            case 1:
                return "Müşteri Listele";
            case 2:
                return "Rapor Al";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

**fragment_sub_page01.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.SubPage01">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etAdi"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/Musteri_Adi" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etSoyadi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etAdi"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/Musteri_Soyadi" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kaydet"
        android:id="@+id/bKaydet"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Listele"
        android:id="@+id/bListele"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bKaydet"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/tvSonuc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etSoyadi"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bListele"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bListele" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SubPage01.java**

```
public class SubPage01 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {


EditText Soyadi,Adi;
Button btnKaydet, bListele;
TextView sonuc;
int counter=0;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);

   /** String[] dizi={"gulay","enes","fadime","haydar"};
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvListe);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dizi);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    */

    return rootView;

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnKaydet= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bKaydet);
    btnKaydet.setOnClickListener(this);
    sonuc=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvSonuc);
    Soyadi=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etSoyadi);
    Adi=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etAdi);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

   /// final Veritabani veritabani=new Veritabani(getActivity()); ??

    String ad=Adi.getText().toString();

    String soyad=Soyadi.getText().toString();

  ///  veritabani.open(); ??

    sonuc.setText(ad+"  eklendi");

    /// veritabani.close(); ??

}
```

}

**This is my logcat**

```
12-13 07:39:39.206 29293-29293/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.guly.projecttabmenu-2/lib/x86
    12-13 07:39:39.511 29293-29309/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    12-13 07:39:39.511 29293-29309/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe9921960, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    12-13 07:39:45.831 29293-29309/com.guly.projecttabmenu W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    12-13 07:39:45.831 29293-29309/com.guly.projecttabmenu W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe8ebdb80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    12-13 07:39:47.775 29293-29309/com.guly.projecttabmenu E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeb0ed870
    12-13 07:39:53.740 29293-29309/com.guly.projecttabmenu W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    12-13 07:39:53.741 29293-29309/com.guly.projecttabmenu W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe9921c80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    12-13 07:39:54.147 29293-29309/com.guly.projecttabmenu E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeb0ed800
    12-13 07:39:59.443 29293-29293/com.guly.projecttabmenu E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEcustomerinformation": syntax error
    12-13 07:39:59.443 29293-29293/com.guly.projecttabmenu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.guly.projecttabmenu, PID: 29293
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcustomerinformation": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEcustomerinformation(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, adi TEXT NOT NULL, soyadi TEXT NOT NULL)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                                 at com.guly.projecttabmenu.Veritabani$DbHelper.onCreate(Veritabani.java:42)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                 at com.guly.projecttabmenu.Veritabani.open(Veritabani.java:57)
                                                                                 at layout.SubPage01.onClick(SubPage01.java:74)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Thank you =) You are perfect !! this fixed my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

You have missed space after CREATE TABLE statement.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CUSTOMERINFORMATION_TABLE + "(" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ROW_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ROW_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
```